# How can set by defaut a jupyter dark theme on aws glue notebooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, aws-glue

i m looking for a speficif way to set this configuration programmatically, on the top of the notebook,  in the magics settings , something like this :

`%%configure { "jupyter_theme": "dark" }`

this is the actual way to doing this
[image: manual Glue dark]